# "confusing logical error if statement with logical operator 'and' "

Tags: python, for-loop

I found it weird while I was coding (python 3.7) about `"and"` inside if statement. I expected all the values except `(3,3)` but it ignored all which consist of 3 and output is :

```
(0,0)(0,1)(0,2)(1,0)(1,1)(1,2)(2,0)(2,1)(2,2)
```

```
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        if (i !=3 and j !=3):
           print(i,j)
```

Comment: I think it's clearer if we use [De Morgan law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws),  `i != 3 and j != 3` is equivalent to `not (i == 3 or j == 3)`

Comment: In english, the condition translates to: "`if i is not 3 AND j is not 3, print something.`" Now ask yourself, when i is 3, does the condition satisfy? (or in other words, neither j nor i can be 3, for something to be printed)

Comment: It seems quite clear to me, `i != 3 and j != 3` is just "both `i` and `j` are different than three". So neither can be three.

Comment: You just had an issue with the if condition @reza

Answer (score 0):

Your previous conditional statement `i !=3 and j !=3` translates to `not (i == 3 or j == 3)`, which excludes `3` from both i and j, hence you see no `3` in the output

The correct conditional statement is actually `not (i == 3 and j == 3)` which translates to `i != 3 or j !=3`

Changing the if-condition then according to either of the conditional statements will yield the correct output

```
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        #Or not (i == 3 and j == 3)
        if i != 3 or j !=3:
            print(i,j)
```

The output will be

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
0 3
1 0
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 0
2 1
2 2
2 3
3 0
3 1
3 2
```

Answer (score 0):

For your expected outcome , you should use OR operator as in case of AND operator, like (0,3) -> T F -> F results in False so it will not be printed 
but in case of OR -> (10,3) -> T F -> T. check the truth tables for AND and OR.